# Compare NSURL String and simple Swift String

Tags: ios, swift, string-comparison, xcode-6.2

I have a function in Xcode 6.2 where I want to compare a URL returned from webview and compare it with a static string. I am doing it like this:

```
  func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView){
        let currentURL = webView.request?.URL
        print("Webview did finish load ")
        println(currentURL)



        if (webView.request?.URL == "Optional(http://addi.star.com/adminpanel/first.php/login)") 
        {

        println("voilaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa")

        // code for dissming the view
        //self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        }
   }
```

...but it's not working. Can someone please explain how I can compare currentURL to static URL so that I can dismiss the view? I think I'm missing the types to compare it successfully, but there must be a way to do this...

Comment: How can i compare the hard coded value with  webView.request?.URL

Comment: Why do you compare with a string where "Optional(" is embedded, clearly by mistake? Unwrap the static URL value first before making a string of it. // Also, do you have a specific reason to use Xcode 6? You should upgrade - Swift has evolved a lot.

Comment: i am new to ios development and learning things and how they work around . can you show me how i have to do it properly as in like example ? so that i can move forward in my learning .. and the system i am using is bound to use xcode 6.2 . please help me solve the problem

Comment: maybe convert the url to a string like so, and force unwrap the optional:           if (String(webView.request!.URL) == "http://addi.star.com/adminpanel/first.php/login")

Comment: i added the optional in static string because webView.request?.URL gives me Optional(http://addi.star.com/adminpanel/first.php/login) but i cant make an comparison

Comment: You're seeing this backwards. Instead of wrongly including the Optional in the String, *unwrap* the URL Optional before using it in comparison with a normal string...

Comment: webView.request?.URL what type is it ?? can it be convert to string  ?

Comment: optional is the embeded when i get the url from webview . how can i split it but that would be out of this questions scope ? so i think you got what i want to do .?

Comment: @bearacuda13 your solution didn't worked

Comment: @Addi.Star Well sorry to be blunt but what you need at this stage is simply to learn the very basics of Swift before asking questions on Stack Overflow. The Swift manual by Apple is great, read it. The chapter about Optionals will be of great help for your issue: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330

Comment: @EricAya thank you for your help . i am already reading it .

Comment: @Addi.Star Oh no! what was the error message?

Comment: @bearacuda13 if (String(webView.request!.URL)    String in this statement causing the syntax error. illegal to use here or may be the version which i am using was not accepting this

Comment: ok, I didn't really test it myself. that exclamation point should go somewhere to force a value from being optional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just compare string

```
if (webView.request?.url?.absoluteString == "http://addi.star.com/adminpanel/first.php/login"){
    //code
}
```

Comment: Damm but there is exception situation. If you are extracting link from string using linkdetector it will return you "https://www.google.com" after loading same in webview webview.request.absolutestring will be "https://www.google.com/" the extra "/" at end will cause mismatch

Answer (score 0):

```
 func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView){
            let currentURL = webView.request?.URL
            print("Webview did finish load ")
            println(currentURL)

    if let urlStr = webView?.request?.URL?.absoluteString where urlStr == "http://addi.star.com/adminpanel/first.php/login"{
        println("voilaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa")

           // code for dissming the view
            //self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }


        }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: OP uses Xcode 6. I think `where` appeared in Swift 2.2 (Xcode 7).